# Запись hex в бинарный файл, c++

Tags: c++, fstream, hex

Мне надо записать данный hex-код в бинарный файл. Я уже когда-то писал похожую программу, но сейчас, когда пытаюсь, перенести этот код в другой проект возникает ошибка: вместо данного кода в hex многократно записывается один и тот же байт (каждый раз разный):

[image: Результат записи в хекс]

При этом, если писать в старом старом решении, всё будет работать отлично. В чём может быть проблема?

Код, который используется для сохранения файла:

```
FILE* ptr = fopen(output_path.c_str(), "wb");
char* c = new char[2];

for (size_t i = 0; i < hex_str.size(); i += 2)
{
    input = "";
    input += hex_str[i];
    input += hex_str[i + 1];
    input = strtol(input.c_str(), &c, 16);
    fwrite(&input, 1, 1, ptr);
}
fclose(ptr);
```

Пытался найти разницу в настройках между старым и новым решениями, но при изменениях появлялись новые ошибки.

Так же буду рад, если найдутся альтернативные записи string в hex, но очень интересно, почему именно это решение работает не везде.

Значения переменной input точно изменяется, вот часть вывода перед преобразованием в hex-формат:

[image: Перед преобразованием в hex-формат]

и после преобразования в hex-формат:

[image: После преобразования]

Comment: Ну так посмотрите в код. В строке input Вы собираете строку, но пишете всегда первый символ. Собственно, логично и получается

Comment: @KoVadim, дело не в этом. 
К концу цикла (перед fwrite) input принимает значение, готовое к записи в бин файле. И, насколько помню, он записывает 1 целый объект input размером 1 в ptr (если не прав, буду рад, если поправите).

Если бы он записывал _только_ первый символ, то:
1. В файле каждый байт был бы хотя бы разным, а не одинаковым.
2. В файле каждый байт не был случайным (то есть, при первом пробеге мы в файле получаем A0 в каждом байте, а при следующем -- C0, потом можем получить B0 и тд при одних и тех же входных данных).
3. Программа бы так же не работала в другом решении.

Comment: У Вас первый байт строки не меняется. А его Вы и пишете. Все остальное - домыслы. Что там в другом приложении - никто не знает. Самое смешное, Вы пишете первый полубайт, даже не байт

Comment: @KoVadim 
Добавил в вопрос картинки, доказывающие, что захватывается не один байт, а разные, и то, что происходит их преобразование. 
Но где-то на моменте записи происходит что-то мне не понятное, которое всё преобразует в одинаковый байт. 

К тому же, заметил один небольшой мой промах: в цикле я оставил name.size() -- переменную, которая используется у меня в коде, хотя в примере я переименовал эту переменную в hex_str, чтобы посещающим страницу было проще разобраться.

Comment: Input это std::string?

Comment: @KoVadim Да, input это std::string;

Comment: и записываете в файл первый байт объекта string. а лучше конечно писать input.c_str() и похоже 2 байта.

Comment: @KoVadim 
Если поставить размерность 2 байта, то он бы не правильно записывал код (не те размеры, да и тоже повторяться будет). 
Но замена &input на input.c_str() в fwrite помогла. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментариях помогли разобраться с вопросом. Код заработал при замене строки

```
fwrite(&input, 1, 1, ptr);
```

на

```
fwrite(input.c_str(), 1, 1, ptr);
```